# upload 80GB file to azure blob storage

Tags: azure

I am looking for a utility to upload an 80 GB file (a VHD) to Azure blob storage. I have tried Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata which is a good tool, but the upload keeps failing. I tried Azure Storage Explorer also, without success. My internet provider is ATT Uverse and I get 16 Mpbs down and 1.4 Mbps up according to speedtest.net. This should be enough to upload the file in a few days, if my math is correct.

81,920 MB
1.4 Mbps= .175 MB/s
5.4 days

Is there a way to break a file into pieces and upload in parts to azure blob storage? Am I going to have to write my own C# client to upload the file? I could do this, but I was hoping to find a good tool that would do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this post: [Uploading a file in Azure Blob Storage](http://thecodegarden.net/uploading-to-azure-storage/).
It explains how you can upload any file to Blob storage with a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried AzCopy tool? This tool is very fast. Check here : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx

If that doesn't work, you have to write code to split the file and upload it.
You can take help of the below code :
http://tuvianblog.com/2011/06/28/how-to-upload-large-size-fileblob-to-azure-storage-using-asp-netc/

Comment: I tried AzCopy, but it timed out. :( I also looked at the source code, but I'm not sure which dlls to reference and it doesn't have any code to download.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you've tried using the Azure Powershell to do it?  the Add-AzureVhd command?

For more info check this out:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/

Having said all this, I've tried to upload a 57GB vhd using this method and it keeps failing after about 40 mins or so, so I'm constantly having to resume the process.  It worked fine 1st time for a test 20MB vhd I created though.

**UDPATE:** I got it to work eventually though powershell, the problem for me was the vhd file I was trying to upload, not the process I was using.